# show radio button values in form

Tags: php, radio-button

In this code in php, don´t show the values of radio buttons, echo don´t work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Probando radio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="m" checked>Mujer
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="h">Hombre
    </form>
    <? php
       $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
      // print ($sexo);
      echo $sexo;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Besides the answer given below, you also have a space in this `<? php` that will outright fail, if that's what your code really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify the form action and add a submit button. upon submit, $_POST['sexo'] should contain your result (m or h)

Comment: *"specify the form action and add a submit button"* - Seeing that the OP's using both their form and PHP inside the same page, specifying the form's action isn't required, since omitting it defaults to self. What the OP isn't doing is using a conditional `isset()` and/or `!empty()`. But yeah, a submit button will be required.

Comment: Another thing; see my comment to the OP under their question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended fix, but it will work:

Change:

```
 <form  method="POST">
```

To:

```
 <form action="#"  method="post">
```

NOTE:  Technically method should be lower case.  It's an XHTML requirement.  You would be penalized by W3C mobileOK validation.